# Is there any way to trigger draggable programmatically to sort list inside it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

I'm working on sorting list of items depending on type of sort "DESC" or "ASC" on draggable sort and when sort was finished on serve side then create trigger to append new list of sorted items to draggable list.

after edit :

```
<dragable 
       :element="'ul'"
       @choose="onChoose" 
       class="dragArea" 
       @add="onAdd" 
       :list="relatedIndexes" 
       :options="style" 
       @change="orderRelatedIndexes($event)" 
       :topIndexId="index.id">

       <li class="right-line" v-for="(indexItem, i) in relatedIndexes" :key="i" >
             <page-item-indexes-list :index="indexItem" />
        </li>
</dragable>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tccMg.png)

Comment: it possible, but please provide some code and we will help you ...

Comment: i'm trying to put my code into codepen website but it's faild, so should i put my code into comment

Comment: draggable sort is working with me but what i was looking for when i press on button DESC then sort draggable must change sort.